# How to initialize javascript after *ngIf content loaded in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I have one div and inside div i have some html now i want to initilize script for that html after content loaded for once.

```
<div class="m-stack m-stack--ver m-stack--desktop  m-header__wrapper" *ngIf="isLogin == 'true'">
```

Comment: in Angular 2+ you have function:  `ngAfterViewInit() { }`

Comment: that what you mean after the page load?

Comment: yes i call layout.headerInin() in ngAfterViewInit() function but it will call init function first and then load if content so not working

Comment: do you want to show content if `isLogin=='true'` ???

Comment: yes if condition true then content loaded

Comment: do you try do it with `[hidden]` and boolean param instesd of `ngIf`

Comment: yes i try but in hidden it will hide content so when i initilize some script using id then it will not work properly

Comment: Can you show all the div I mean what you try to do inside...

Answer (score 0):

For this issue You need to create one Flag [AfterViweInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

```
this.isLogin = false;

ngOnInit() {
var data = this._userService.verify().subscribe(res => {
    if (res) {
       this.isLogin = 'true';
    } else {
       this.isLogin = 'false';
    }
 });
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    mLayout.initHeader();
    setTimeout(()=>{  
      this.isLogin = true;
    },100);
}–
```

in your html page

```
<div class="m-stack m-stack--ver m-stack--desktop  m-header__wrapper" *ngIf="isLogin">
```

This might help you

Comment: ngOnInit() {
     var data = this._userService.verify().subscribe(res => 
     {
         if(res)
         {
             this.isLogin = 'true';
         }
         else{
              this.isLogin = 'false';
         }
         });
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {

        mLayout.initHeader();

    }

Comment: @Maulik then use settimeout function

Comment: but it is proper way to use setTimeout function?

Comment: yes if i use this then it work's but i want  another way

Comment: answer updated bro & you need to use this...timeout or you need to use https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/...

Answer (score 0):

Put the script inside the lifecycle hook for ngAfterViewInit()

```
export class YourClass implements  AfterViewInit {

// Add this method
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this code will execute after the ngif has been rendered
    this.logIt('AfterViewInit');
    this.doSomething();
  }

}
```

From the docs: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Comment: i already write this  ngAfterViewInit() {

        mLayout.initHeader();

    }